# How hidden the user_filter_form to a specific role?

Tags: 7, users

How can I hidden with `alter_form` to hide the `user_filter_form` in the page of list of users to a specific role?

Answer (score 0):

`hook_form_alter()` wouldn't actually be the best place for this; the form is actually called in from [`user_admin()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.admin.inc/function/user_admin/7) so the best place for your code would be [`hook_page_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7).

The first thing you should do is create a custom permission that you can assign to the role:

```
function MYMODULE_permission() {
  return array(
    'access user filter form' =>  array(
      'title' => t('Access User Filter Form')
    ),
  );
}
```

Then implement `hook_page_alter()` to hide the form:

```
function MYMODULE_page_alter(&$page) {
  // Make sure this is the right page
  if (arg(0) == 'admin' && arg(1) == 'people') {
    // Make sure filter form actually exists
    if (isset($page['content']['system_main']['user_filter_form'])) {
      // Check user access
      if (!user_access('access user filter form')) {
        // Deny access to the form if necessary
        $page['content']['system_main']['user_filter_form']['#access'] = FALSE;
      }
    }
  }
}
```